# Persist header and trailer in split command in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

I've a CSV file which contains a header line, multiple data lines and a footer line(which contains the data line count). I'm splitting the file based on the size(which is 5MB).

After splitting the files I need the header to be persisted in all the files after the split and also the count needs to be changed in the footer accordingly as number of data lines may vary.

```
split -d -a3 -b 5M --additional-suffix=_$(date '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S').CSV TEST-REPORT-D-INR-TEMP_20230905211012.CSV TEST-REPORT-D-INR-TEMP_
```

**Sample File**

```
H|INR|TEST|YYYYMMDDHHMMSS
DATALINE1
DATALINE2
DATALINE3
DATALINE4
DATALINE5
T|5
```

After the split the output I need is like

**File 1**

```
H|INR|TEST|YYYYMMDDHHMMSS
DATALINE1
DATALINE2
T|2
```

**File 2**

```
H|INR|TEST|YYYYMMDDHHMMSS
DATALINE3
DATALINE4
T|2
```

**File 3**

```
H|INR|TEST|YYYYMMDDHHMMSS
DATALINE5
T|1
```

Comment: Should the output be split mid-line at the 5MB boundaries so, for example, the last data line of file1 could be `DATAL` and the first data line of file 2 `INE1`? If not and lines don't end at exactly 5M boundaries should the first file contain that last complete line just under or just over 5MB? Does the 5MB output file size include the size of the header and footer or just of the data lines? Does your input contain any multi-byte characters? [edit] your question to provide those answers.

Comment: First, remove the header and the footer completely.  Then split the file.  Then add the header and footer to each file.  Inefficient, but simple and robust (?).

Comment: Your sample file is already not valid CSV (the last line should be `T|5||`, because in csv, every line needs to have the same number of fields. Also you splitting does not make sense. You have to split at the end of a logical CSV line, not somewhere in between.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following assumes 1 byte characters.

You apparently have structured data (CSV), so you cannot really split at 5MB because you will probably split in the middle of data lines. And considering that you want significantly more than just splitting, it's maybe time to use `awk`, instead of `split`:

```
awk -v size="$(( 5 * 1024 * 1024 ))" -v suff="_$(date '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S').CSV" \
  -v pref='TEST-REPORT-D-INR-TEMP_' '
  NR == 1 {h = $0; size -= length + 11; next}
  NR == 2 {p = $0; next}
  s + length(p) + 1 > size && t < 1 {print "Error: max size too small"; exit}
  s + length(p) + 1 > size {print "T|" t > f; close(f); s = 0; t = 0}
  s == 0 {f = sprintf("%s%03d%s", pref, n, suff); print h > f; n += 1}
  {print p > f; s += length(p) + 1; t += 1; p = $0}
  END {print "T|" t > f; close(f)}' TEST-REPORT-D-INR-TEMP_20230905211012.CSV
```

Step by step explanations:

- We declare and assign a set of variables (`size`, `suff`...) with the `-v` option. Other variables take a default value (0 for numeric values, empty strings for string values).
- When encountering the first input line (`NR == 1`) we store it in `h`, subtract its length plus 11 from `size`, and move to the next line. The 11 accounts for the footer and the two newline characters at the end of the header and footer. Adapt to your needs.
- When encountering the second line (`NR == 2`) we store it in `p` and move to the next. In the next steps we always work on the previous line in `p`, not the current one. This is a way to skip the last line that you don't want in your output.
- If the current size `s` is too large to add `p` and a newline character, but we did not add any line yet (`t < 1`) we print an error message and exit to avoid infinite loop.
- Else, if the current size `s` is too large to add `p` and a newline character, we print the footer, close the file, reset current size `s` and number of printed data lines `t`.
- If current size `s` is zero we compute the name of the next output file (`f`), print the header in it (`print h > f`) and increment the file index (`n += 1`).
- For all lines (but the two first) we print the previous line (`print p > f`), update the current size with its length (`s += length(p) + 1`), increment the data lines count (`t += 1`), and store the current line in `p`.

At the end (`END`) we print the last footer.

Comment: Hi @renaud how about the footer count? I've tried the answer which you've posted files got generated but the footer count is there in the last file only but it needs to be there in all the files

Comment: And also can you please explain in brief what's the above command will do step by step

Comment: I've 35001 data lines in the CSV file. In one file I've 31003 data lines and the count in footer also matched but in the second file it has 3998 data line but the footer count is showing as 35001 which is the total count

Comment: And I need the file size to be of 5MB even after adding the header and trailer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255410/discussion-between-ashok-and-renaud-pacalet).

Comment: Hi Renaud any update on the last file footer count?

Comment: why we are subtracting its length plus 11 from size? @renaud

Comment: As explained: to account for the footer and the two newline characters at the end of the header and footer.

Answer (score 1):

This (untested) might be what you want, assuming the "5MB" output file size excludes the head and tail line sizes, using GNU awk for "inplace" editing and `ENDFILE`:

```
mkdir output &&
cd output &&
hd=$(head -n 1 ../TEST-REPORT-D-INR-TEMP_20230905211012.CSV) &&
sed '1d;$d' ../TEST-REPORT-D-INR-TEMP_20230905211012.CSV |
split -d -a3 -b 5M --additional-suffix=_$(date '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S').CSV - TEST-REPORT-D-INR-TEMP_ &&
awk -v head="$hd" -i inplace 'FNR==1{print head} {print} ENDFILE{print "T|" FNR}' *
```

I'm using `sed` to remove the first and last line of the input file before the `split` (which is why `split` uses `-` instead of a file name for input) so that:

1. The `awk` script doesn't have to deal with removing the last input file before printing the new tail line to the final output file.
2. The `awk` script isn't affected by the order in which `*` expands to it's input file names.
3. It's easy to replace the awk script with a shell loop if necessary.
4. You could, if you like, update the `split` call to remove the size of the input head and tail lines from the `5MB` so after they're added back to the output files you get output file sizes as close as possible to `5MB` each (the size difference between each output file except the last being how many chars are in the number of lines shown after the `T|` at the end of each output file).

The above assumes the number of output files from the `split` won't exceed `ARG_MAX` when `awk` is called to operate on them.

If you don't have GNU awk or `ARG_MAX` is exceeded, then replace this:

```
awk -v head="$hd" -i inplace 'FNR==1{print head} {print} ENDFILE{print "T|" FNR}' *
```

with this:

```
tmp=$(mktemp) &&
for file in *; do
    { printf '%s\n' "$hd"; cat "$file"; printf 'T|%d\n' $(wc -l "$file"); } > "$tmp" &&
    mv -- "$tmp" "$file"
done
```

I kept the `split` arguments as you had them and didn't think about them under the assumption you know what you're doing with that part of it.

Answer (score 0):

Splitting a line-based file into byte-sized chunks will most likely corrupt the data. Use the `-l NUM` switch to split on line-endings.

Assuming an average line-length of 10 bytes, you want to split into files of 500k lines. In case you are using GNU coreutils split, you have the `--filter` switch which could be used like this:

```
sed '1d;$d' infile |
split -l 500k --filter '{ head -n1 infile; cat; printf "T|%d\n" 500000; } > $FILE'
```